# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in custom library

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a small project and I wanted to export an array of JSON objects into a text file. I came across [this](http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/snippets/console-save/console-save.js) handy `console.save()` function for Chrome Dev Tools, and decided to use it. My library, [leapcapjs](https://github.com/Carpetfizz/leapcapjs) has an exposed function that is the following:

```
LeapCap.getSavedFrames = function(){
    return SAVED_FRAMES;
}
```

where `SAVED_FRAMES` is a global variable. In order to export this array to a string, I typed the following into my dev console:

`console.save(LeapCap.getSavedFrames());`

As a result, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Anyone know what the problem could be? Thanks!

EDIT: `SAVED_FRAMES` is populated with `frameData` objects:

```
SAVED_FRAMES.push(frameData);
```

A `frameData` object is made like this:

```
LEAP_CONTROLLER.on('frame', function (frame) {
        if (!PAUSE_LEAP) {
            var frameData = {
                'interaction_box': frame.interactionBox,
                'hands': frame.hands
            };
            drawWith(frameData);
        }
    });
```

Could some of the [LeapJS](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap_Classes.html) API objects be causing the problem? If so, how can I stop this?

Comment: Does the contents of `SAVED_FRAMES` point to itself anywhere?

Comment: some property in the returned object from getSavedFrames has a circular reference, ie a child property refers to a parent object

Comment: As an aside, get used to this error; you'll see it a LOT when trying to display JSON objects in Javascript.

Comment: @alex, nope it does not.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I've updated the original post with how `SAVED_FRAMES` is populated. Maybe that might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [circumvent ERROR Converting circular structure to JSON when doing JSON.stringify()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410162/circumvent-error-converting-circular-structure-to-json-when-doing-json-stringify)