# How do I post a complex object to an MVC 4 controller via Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an object called **DrawDie** with the following properties:

```
ID
PlantID : int
QtyOnHand : int
SizeUS : double
SizeMetric : double
CaseSize : string
Style : string
```

I have an object called **DieOrder** with the following properties:

```
ID : int
DrawDie : DrawDie
DrawDieID : int
PlantID : int
PurchaseOrder : string
Qty : int
```

I would like to post my object to an MVC controller via an Ajax request.  I would prefer not to use a 3rd party library.  I am trying to post it like this:

```
        var DieOrder = new Object();
        var DrawDie = new Object();

        DieOrder.Qty = $("#Qty").val();
        DieOrder.DrawDieID = $("#DrawDieID").val();


        DrawDie.CaseSize = $("#DrawDie_CaseSize").val();
        DrawDie.Qty = $("#Qty").val();          
        DrawDie.ID = dieID;
        DrawDie.QtyOnHand = 0;
        DrawDie.SizeUS = $("#DrawDie_SizeUS");
        DrawDie.SizeMetric = $("#DrawDie_SizeMetric");
        DrawDie.PlantID = $("#PlantID").val();
        DrawDie.IsTransfer = "N";

        DieOrder.PlantID = $("#PlantID").val();
        DieOrder.OrderedBy = $("#OrderedBy").val();
        DieOrder.PurchaseOrder = $("#PurchaseOrder").val();
        DieOrder.DrawDie = DrawDie;


        $.ajax({
            url: "Order/OrdDie",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(DieOrder),
            success: handleData


        });

    });
```

I have two questions.  One, is my approach way off or is it okay ?  I am getting an UncaughtType error: Converting circular structure to JSON.  How do I restructure my request so I do not get such an error?  I am unsure of why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Update:

```
 DrawDie.SizeUS = $("#DrawDie_SizeUS").val();
 DrawDie.SizeMetric = $("#DrawDie_SizeMetric").val();
```

I was missing the .val()

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5410200/487940

Comment: why you dont use ajax.beginform for this

Comment: Pathachiever11.  I checked out the posting but it really did not clarify things for me.  I do not know why I am getting the circular reference error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're really having is that your controller is interpreting all of the contents of your `DieOrder` object as arguments to your controller action.

If your controller action looks like this...

```
[HttpPost]
public void OrdDie(OrderDieViewModel model)
{
    // Some operations
}
```

...Then the data that your stringifying should look like this:

```
{
    'model': DieOrder
}
```

...so, you're really just missing a step prior to making your `$.ajax` call:

```
var DrawDie = {
    // Properties...
};

var DieOrder = {
    // Properties...
    'DrawDie': DrawDie
};

var data = {
    'model': DieOrder
};

$.ajax({
    // Spec object here.
});
```

In short?  Your data object's contents **must match the argument list of the action you are calling.**  This means that if you pass only a model to your JSON action, your data object must have only one member: the JavaScript representation of that model object.

Comment: Andrew.  Thanks for the info, but I am never getting to the controller.   I am getting an UncaughtType error: Converting circular structure to JSON in my javascript code so the ajax request is never made.

Comment: Aah, my apologies!  I don't see any circular reference, though.  Are you showing us everything (that you can) about the JavaScript data structures that you're trying to send to the server?

Comment: It turns out that when I remove the following line in my javascript the UncaughtType error: Converting circular structure to JSON error goes away.  Any ideas why ?

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to include the line that makes the circular structure error go away...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType: 'json' to your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Order/OrdDie",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(_data),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: handleData
});
```

In addition you can initialize JS objects like this:

```
var DieOrder = {};
var DrawDie = {};
```

I hope this help!